# React app always going to home route after receiving the response from the backend(node.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes

after I receive the response from the backend and based on it trying to redirect to a different route
but no matter what i do the app redirects to the signin route
and display my http request on the link although it is a post request

i tried getting the response and do nothing with it (i did only fetch (no then) and got the response ) it worked but when try to go to different the problem happens
and i know for sure that response is getting back

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin' , {
      method: 'post' , 
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.signInEmail,
        password: this.state.signInPassword
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data === 'success') {
        this.props.onRouteChange('home');
      }
    })    
  }





onRouteChange= (route) => {
    if (route==='signout'){
      this.setState({isSignedIn:false})
    }
    else if (route ==='home') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn:true})
    }
    this.setState({route:route})
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation  isSignedIn={this.state.isSignedIn} onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange}/>
      <ParticlesBg color="#282c34" num={200} type="cobweb" bg={true} />
      { this.state.route === 'home' ?
         <div> <Logo />
         <Rank />
         <ImgLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>
         <Facerec box={this.state.box} imageurl={this.state.imageurl} />
         </div>
       
       :
      (this.state.route === 'signin'  ? <Signin  onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange} />
       : <SignUp loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange} />
           )
      }
    </div>
  );}
```

Comment: First question off-topic: are you working on a project out of your control, or are you just getting started and learning React? If it's the latter I suggest you not to use Class based components since they are from the dinosaur age, use Functional components instead. Next, what's the unexpected behavior if you set your code to redirect to Home and it successfully redirects to Home, as mentioned in your post??

Comment: sorry i meant it redirects to the signin route . after i receive the response instantly the app routes to (localgost:defaul port) and diplays the form parametres in the link above as in get request ( and im new to react )

Comment: by any chance, is the button being clicked inside a <form> and the button does not have type = "button", thus having type = "submit" and the form is submitted when this button is pressed? If you add type="button" to that button element, is the behavior you described gone?

Comment: Thank you very much @André Benedetti, It worked